# transitions property not working in safari browser

Tags: css, safari, transition

Css Transition effects on my website don't work in safari (tested on latest version). And transition is working well in others browser tested in Chrome, firefox, and Opera.

My code is the following:

```
.navbar-inverse ul a{
     overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
     transition: color 0.5s;
}

.navbar-inverse  ul a::before{
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s;
    -o-transition: top 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s;
     transition: top 0.5s;  
}
```

**How to fix it? After that transition works in safari too.**

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you placed the transition property for the element with the pseudo element `before`. Try placing the transition property for the element itself. This is what I mean:

```
.navbar-inverse ul a{
   overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: color,top 0.5s;
  -o-transition: color,top 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: color,top 0.5s;
   transition: color,top 0.5s;
}
```